# Java, How to find the function by reflection through java.lang.reflect.Type rather than Class?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, computer-science, method-invocation

for example, there is a function:

```java
public static void myFunc(List<Double> param) {
    xxxx;
}
```

here I have a `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();`
If I look for the function `myFunc` through reflection, I can only find it through the Calss of the parameter like this:`Method method = XXX.class.getMethod("myFunc", List.class);`, but obviously my passed-in parameter type does not match.

So, is there any good way to find the function through the `Type` of the parameter? More specifically, how to find the appropriate target function by passing-in parameters with generic?

I wrote a DSL using antlr4, and now can infer the Type of each function call parameter, but can't easily find the right function through the parameter Type. And I tried to write a function to find the function through Type, and found that the implementation is very complicated and error-prone.

Comment: You can't easily create `Type`s, as far as I know, so I'm not sure how convenient such an API would be to use.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I'm not trying to create Type. Rather, I want to find compatible target functions through the real parameters with generics.

Comment: It is worth noting that the generic type doesn’t matter during method lookups, because generic types alone cannot distinguish a method.  Meaning, a class cannot have both `myFunc(List<Double>)` and `myFunc(List<Integer>)`.  Therefore, it will always be sufficient to use Class.getMethod for this.

Comment: They does cannot exist at the same time. However, I found a function through` Class`, and I can't confirm whether my parameter type matches because of the lack of generics @VGR

Comment: Use the [getGenericParameterTypes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericParameterTypes()) method.  For example: `if (((ParameterizedType) method.getGenericParameterTypes()[0]).getActualTypeArguments()[0].equals(Double.class))`  (Since getMethod completed successfully, we know for certain the parameter is List and has one generic type.)

Comment: It seems, you missed Sweeper’s point. You asked for a method to look up a method by `Type`, but to call such a method, you need a `Type` argument. Hence, you have to create such a `Type` first.

Comment: yes, I have created `Type` through such as `ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(List.class, new Type[] {List.class}, null)), ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(Map.class, new Type[] {String.class, Integer.class}, null))`.  
In fact, I can create all Type types, but there is no good way to find functions through Type parameters. 
Here, All methods can be defined under different classes, so even functions with the same name may have functions of List < Integer > and List < Double > argument types.